# Content Delivery on IIS Express 8 64-bit in Windows 8: System.AccessViolationException

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I'm running a web application which calls the Content Delivery API in an IIS Express 8 64-bit environment. The whole thing runs locally in Windows 8.

Whenever I start the application from Visual Studio 2012 and it triggers a call the Juggernet, it shuts down the IIS process and doesn't throw an error in Visual Studio.

The last lines in the Output Window in VS look like this:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Messaging\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Messaging.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in netrtsn.dll
The program '[2924] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).
The program '[2348] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

It seemed like file permission issue, but the whole directory is opened for everyone.

Running the same settings with IIS 8 Express in Windows 7 does seem to work.

Does anyone know what the problem could be and how to fix this?

Comment: Should I state the obvious and say that this configuration was not tested and is not expected to work?

Comment: Ah.. didn't realize that.

Answer (score 4):

CD 2011/2011 SP1 is not supported for IIS 8. The problem is indeed with the JuggerNET dependency. In fact, for the 2013 release, the CD team has upgraded JuggerNET and recreated all proxies from scratch. Don't try it anymore...it should not work (unless you radically change your system).

Comment: I think it's something with Windows 8 in this case. CD 2011 seems to work fine with IIS Express 8 on Windows 7. It must be some extra restrictions on the .NET sandbox in Windows 8. For now I switched to the 32-bit Cassini webserver for local development.