# Is it possible to setup a Content Delivery server on a Window 7 Enterprise based developer machine?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, infrastructure

We have a Linux and Tomcat Content Delivery environment for our Tridion based websites.

We would like to setup our Tridion based JAVA websites to run on our developer’s local machines so they can debug the Broker API code. We have a valid CD license with which unrestricted numbers of local Tridion servers can be setup.

We are planning to accomplish this activity as follows:

1. Copy the published websites directory to a windows based environment.
2. Setup the Content Delivery server on a machine with Window 7 Enterprise, Eclipse  and Tomcat.
3. Update the respective configuration files to interact with the database server.

I checked http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=publist_home  ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) but there "Microsoft Windows 2008 R2 SP1" is mentioned.

Now I have doubts whether CD will work with Window 7 Enterprise in my case.

Could somebody help me by pointing out any other challenges I should consider at this moment and whether or not what I want to do is possible with Window 7 Enterprise?

Comment: I've seen this approach back with Windows XP with the biggest catch on publishing files (sounds like your manual copy will address this). Your biggest gotchas aside from making it work will likely be license updates for each "server," handling any published files (is everything through the broker?), and giving developers access to the broker database credentials (not so much a problem for development).

Comment: Oh and my favorite: confusion on what's published and/or environment specific. Be clear on what's managed--I've seen developers accidentally check-in a configuration file or a developer-specific license/configuration end up on a server. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Tomcat and the deployed Tridion jar files in Tomcat will run on anything where a JDK (64/32 bit) can be installed, which means a full Java Tridion front end can run on Windows 7 as well.

Make sure to install the latest JDK release of the 1.6 branch, as that is the required version for Tridion 2011.

Comment: Same counts for IIS, you can use the local IIS on Windows 7 and add the required files in the `bin` dir and have a fully working Content Delivery site for a developer (on Win 7 Professional even). It is not a supported setup (as mentioned in the documentation), but for a developer it should be fine.

Comment: Watch the log files for any errors.  Most likely the errors would be related to the versions of the JDK and JRE installed.  Also, make sure the CD files are visible to Java via Classpath or location.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your Tridion Version

The recommended Windows version for Tridion 2011 SP1 is 2008 R2 SP1, However Tridion still supports from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 R2. Tridion 2011 doesn't support Java 7.

The recommended Windows version for Tridion 2013 is Windows 2012, However Tridion still supports Windows 2008 R2 SP1. Tridion 2013 does support Java 7.

Window 7 Enterprise is not supported, it might work, but I would strong recommend to use a supported version, maybe running a virtual machine would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question - Yes you can.

Now to learn about challenges and thoughts of experts you may want to refer these two already asked questions on the same topic couple of months ago:

[challenge-in-configuring-the-cd-website-on-developers-machine](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/challenge-in-configuring-the-cd-website-on-developers-machine)

[content-delivery-on-iis-express-8-64-bit-in-windows-8-system-accessviolationexc](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/823/content-delivery-on-iis-express-8-64-bit-in-windows-8-system-accessviolationexc)

The only concern that I see is that if there are any issue that you are not able to resolve, I suspect that you won't get any help from SDL Tridion Helpdesk either.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I do'nt think so.:-) as i am not going to play with the already configured infrastructure